# How to create wrapper for NGX-bootstrap popover

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive, wrapper, ngx-bootstrap

i would like to create wrapper for ngx bootstrap popover as component or directive for my application,

Anybody have an idea for how to create ? and please give me an example

Answer (score 1):

i resolved by,  extends ngx PopoverDirective in my directive